# Using dynamic variables to pass in custom objects

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm scraping data from a variety of pages on a site, and I want to assign points to a total score based on whether or not elements (H1s, alt tags, meta titles; that sort of thing) exist, are unique or are duplicates. I'd like to create a method that can do this for every element I scrape, which I am using custom classes to store.

```
public class PageData
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Analytics { get; set; }

    public bool Paginated { get; set; }

    public bool Flash { get; set; }

    public bool Iframe { get; set; }

    public bool NoIndexFollow { get; set; }

    public bool SchemaTag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AltTag> AltTags { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Canonical> Canonicals { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MetaTitle> MetaTitles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MetaDesc> MetaDescs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogLocation> BlogLocations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H1> H1s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H2> H2s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H3> H3s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ViewState> ViewStates { get; set; }
}


public class H1
{
    public H1() { }

    public H1(int id, string h1)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.H1String = h1;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return H1String;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string H1String { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }


}
```

Method to try allocate scores

```
public void pageCheck(SiteData site, dynamic pageObj, int lowAssignedScore, int highAssignedScore, int totalScore)
    {
        List<string> uniqueCheckList = new List<string>();
        bool uniqueCheck = true;

        foreach (PageData page in site.PageDatas)
        {
            if (pageObj.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var modelObj in pageObj)
                {
                    if (uniqueCheckList.Contains(modelObj.ToString()))
                    {
                        totalScore =+ lowAssignedScore;
                        uniqueCheck = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    uniqueCheckList.Add(modelObj.ToString());
                }
                if (uniqueCheck)
                {
                    totalScore += highAssignedScore;
                }
            }
    }
```

I'm instantiating a new page object to pass in which element of the page I want:

```
PageData page = new PageData();

pageCheck(site, page.H1s, 4, 6, totalScore);
```

When I pass in page.H1s it is coming through as: 
     {System.Collections.Generic.List < Bescoured.Models.PageModels.H1 > }

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do in c#? Or will it not let me due to the static nature of the language? I started off by creating a method that was specific to H1 then trying to make it generic but it looks like I need to make a method for each element.

EDIT:

An example of how I would do it if I had make a method for each element

```
foreach (PageData page in site.PageDatas)
            {
                if (page.H1s.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (H1 h1 in page.H1s)
                    {
                        if (h1s.Contains(h1.H1String))
                        {
                            totalScore += 4;
                            uniqueCheck = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        h1s.Add(h1.H1String);
                    }
                    if (uniqueCheck)
                    {
                        totalScore += 6;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're only using the ToString() method of a element. Why not pass a IEnumerable< string> into it?

```
public void pageCheck(SiteData site, IEnumerable<string> pageObj, int lowAssignedScore, int highAssignedScore, int totalScore)
```

Usage:

```
pageCheck(site, page.H1s.Select(item => item.ToString()), 4, 6, totalScore); 
pageCheck(site, page.AltTags.Select(item => item.ToString()), 4, 6, totalScore);
```

I'll always try to avoid dynamics, unless there's no other option.

Comment: Now pageObj is {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<Bescoured.Models.PageModels.H1,string>} and I'm getting the error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Comment: IEnumerable< > doesn't contain a Count property, use method Count() instead. Besides that, you don't need to check for the Count() before a foreach, the foreach won't execute anything if it's 0

Comment: pageObj ends up being {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<Bescoured.Models.PageModels.H1,string>} which doesn't contain any of the data that I need. What I need it to be is page.H1